# Am having 5 tabs ,When I load from 2nd position to 3rd position my list is not loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Moving From 2nd position to 3rd position my list not refreshing in tablayout

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("matches"), getString(R.string.matches));
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("applied"), getString(R.string.applied));
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("favourites"), getString(R.string.favorites));
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("request"), getString(R.string.request));
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("confirmed"), getString(R.string.confirmed));
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

am used above code to set the five tabs.I passed the string value to identify the tabs, depend on the string value i listed the either favourite , mateches and applied etc.

```
public static final NotificationRequestEmpFragment newInstance(String message) {
        NotificationRequestEmpFragment f = new NotificationRequestEmpFragment();

        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }
```

Above code get the message depend on the message i called the web service api. Now if i in applied list add the job to favourite list it not refershed in the favourite list.

Comment: Please provide some code which you tried, more description, it will help us too much to find out your issue

Comment: adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(NotificationRequestEmpFragment.newInstance("matches",EmployeeNotificationFragment.this), getString(R.string.matches)); ....  viewpager.setAdapter(adapter); above code i used above code add the child fragment to view pager. In EmployeeNotificationFragment get the correspondig values and call the web service apis.

Comment: not enough to detecting your issue, please update your question with more code that relative to your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh fragment using interface in your activity

Comment: i am not used Activity, only used fragment with fragment

Comment: There has to be at least one activity.